# How can i display the second matched regex in sed

Tags: regex, sed

Suppose I have this text

```
The code for 233-CO is the main reason for 45-DFG and this 45-GH
```

Now I have this regexp  `\s[0-9]+-\w+` which matches `233-CO`, `45-DFG` and `45-GH`.

How can I display just the third match `45-GH`?

```
sed -re 's/\s[0-9]+-\w+/\3/g' file.txt
```

where `\3` should be the third regexp match.

Comment: Do you need the third match specifically, or the last one ? What do you want if there are four occurrences of this pattern ?

Comment: I mean is there any way that i can match any numbered regex. like if there are 7 in the row then `\7` should return the 7th pattern matched

Answer (score 2):

Is it mandatory to use `sed`? You could do it with `grep`, using arrays:

```
text="The code for 233-CO is the main reason for 45-DFG and this 45-GH"
matches=( $(echo "$text" | grep -o -m 3 '\s[0-9]\+-\w\+') ) # store first 3 matches in array
echo "${matches[0]} ${matches[2]}" # prompt first and third match
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the last occurence of your pattern, you can use this:

```
$ sed -re 's/.*\s([0-9]+-\w+).*/\1/g' file
45-GH
```

Answer (score 0):

if awk is accepted, there is an awk onliner, you give the No# of match you want to grab, it gives your the matched str.

```
awk -vn=$n '{l=$0;for(i=1;i<n;i++){match(l,/\s[0-9]+-\w+/,a);l=substr(l,RSTART+RLENGTH);}print a[0]}' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo $STR     #so we have 7 matches in str                                                                                                  
The code for 233-CO is the main reason for 45-DFG and this 45-GH,foo 004-AB, bar 005-CC baz 006-DDD and 007-AWK

kent$  n=6       #now I want the 6th match

#here you go:
kent$   awk -vn=$n '{l=$0;for(i=1;i<=n;i++){match(l,/\s[0-9]+-\w+/,a);l=substr(l,RSTART+RLENGTH);}print a[0]}' <<< $STR
 006-DDD
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\b[0-9]+-[A-Z]+\b/\n&\n/3;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/' file
```

- `s/\b[0-9]+-[A-Z]+\b/\n&\n/3` prepend and append `\n` (newlines) to the third (n) pattern in question.
- `s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/` delete the text before and after the pattern

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` for matching and `sed` for printing the occurrence:

```
$ egrep -o '\b[0-9]+-\w+' file | sed -n '1p'
233-CO

$ egrep -o '\b[0-9]+-\w+' file | sed -n '2p'
45-DFG

$ egrep -o '\b[0-9]+-\w+' file | sed -n '3p'
45-GH
```

Or with a little `awk` passing the occurrence to print using the variable `o`:

```
$ awk -v o=1 '{for(i=0;i++<NF;)if($i~/[0-9]+-\w+/&&j++==o-1)print $i}' file
233-CO

$ awk -v o=2 '{for(i=0;i++<NF;)if($i~/[0-9]+-\w+/&&j++==o-1)print $i}' file
45-DFG

$ awk -v o=3 '{for(i=0;i++<NF;)if($i~/[0-9]+-\w+/&&j++==o-1)print $i}' file
45-GH
```